# fscanf() only reads last integer per line

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am trying to use `fscanf` to read a file and store its contents in arrays. Each line contains four integer values, which need to be placed in four different arrays. My code reads each line, but stores the final integer value of each line in all four arrays.

I've tried using `fgets()`, which seemed to cause even more problems. Changing the format in the `fscanf()` call hasn't helped either.

Why is it skipping the first three values of each line?

code:

```
FILE *file;
int process_count, p_id[process_count], io_burst[process_count], priority[process_count], cpu_burst[process_count];

file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (!file) { error("File open failed"); }

process_count = atoi(argv[2]);

for (int i = 0; i < process_count; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(file, "%i %i %i %i", &p_id[i], &cpu_burst[i], &io_burst[i], &priority[i]) < 4)
    {
        error("File read failed");
    }

    printf("p_id: %i\n", p_id[i]);
    printf("cpu_burst: %i\n", cpu_burst[i]);
    printf("io_burst: %i\n", io_burst[i]);
    printf("priority: %i\n\n", priority[i]);
}

fclose(file);
```

input:

```
0           10           4           2
1            8           2           1
2           12           0           5
3            2           4           4
4            8           3           0
5            6           4           2
6            4           0           5
7           16           7           5
8           14           0           1
9            2          10           1
```

output:

```
p_id: 2
cpu_burst: 2
io_burst: 2
priority: 2

p_id: 1
cpu_burst: 1
io_burst: 1
priority: 1

p_id: 5
cpu_burst: 5
io_burst: 5
priority: 5

p_id: 4
cpu_burst: 4
io_burst: 4
priority: 4

p_id: 0
cpu_burst: 0
io_burst: 0
priority: 0

p_id: 2
cpu_burst: 2
io_burst: 2
priority: 2

p_id: 5
cpu_burst: 5
io_burst: 5
priority: 5

p_id: 5
cpu_burst: 5
io_burst: 5
priority: 5

p_id: 1
cpu_burst: 1
io_burst: 1
priority: 1

p_id: 1
cpu_burst: 1
io_burst: 1
priority: 1
```

Comment: What happens if your zero-out the arrays first?

Comment: You need to set the value of `process_count` *before* you use it to specify the sizes of the arrays.  Most likely your arrays are all zero length (though that's not reliable since `process_count` is uninitialized at that point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error:

```
int process_count, p_id[process_count],
```

`process_count` is an uninitialized variable so it cannot be used for an array dimension (or anything else really).

To fix this you could change the code to:

```
int process_count = atoi(argv[2]);

if ( process_count < 1 )
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    // or similar

int p_id[process_count], io_burst[process_count], priority[process_count], cpu_burst[process_count];
```

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. I can't believe how long I spent trying to fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behaviour in your program.

```
int process_count, p_id[process_count], io_burst[process_count], cpu_burst[process_count];
...
process_count = atoi(argv[2]);
```

That code is using `process_count` before it has been intialised.